# EventStore automatic backup

Tags: database, backup, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

Is there a way to automatically backup `EventStore`, didn't find any solution, other than manual scripts/console apps etc. I am using [Get EventStore](https://geteventstore.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of right now I believe your best bet is to either:

1. Create an additional node in a separate environment which asynchronously replicates - this acts as a sort of 'hot backup', however this does NOT protect against data destruction via application or user command (unless you catch it before synchronization).
2. Roll your own script to create copies of the *.chk and other necessary files and drop them off at a secure backup location.

Outside of that, I don't know of any automated/native backup functionality in EventStore.

Here is a link to the current (albeit limited) EventStore backup documentation: http://docs.geteventstore.com/server/3.1.0/database-backup/

Comment: We used a bit of python to do the steps in the eventstore documentation. However when you rsync the chunk that is currently being written it may well trigger a swap to another master, so if your running a cluster staggering the backups of each one is a good idea.